# Problems getting JSON with urllib.URLopener

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, urllib

I have problems getting JSON with `urllib.URLopener` even when I can see it in my navigator.

**CODE:**

```
import urllib
import json
json_obj = urllib.URLopener()
json_obj.retrieve(json_adress, self.home + "/.cache/program/file.json")
```

**ERROR:**

```
('http error', 404, 'Not Found', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7fa73d9b3a28>)
```

5 minutes later I can get it, but another address fails. What is happening?

For example, the URL of the JSON file is:

```
http://webservices.francetelevisions.fr/tools/getInfosOeuvre/v2/?idDiffusion=135842229&catalogue=Pluzz&callback=webserviceCallback_135842229
```

Comment: We don't know. That's the server telling you it is not found, not Python. Perhaps the site uses a CDN and not all machines are updated? Without details on the URL, there is nothing we can do here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will add the json adress with editing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finaly found a solution by adding a header to fork Firefox:

```
json_obj = urllib.URLopener()
json_obj.addheaders = [("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0")]
json_obj.retrieve(json_adress, self.home + "/.cache/program/file.json")
```

Now it works every times!

Comment: It is more likely the CDN is currently up to date. CDN updates are not continuous.

Comment: Even if the user agent header makes a difference, it would be an indication that some CDN endpoints are configured differently. And you'd still run into rollout issues from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to access is hosted on a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), and not all servers appear to have the content you requested:

```
$ host webservices.francetelevisions.fr
webservices.francetelevisions.fr is an alias for www-es.francetelevisions.fr.
www-es.francetelevisions.fr is an alias for francetv.fr.edgesuite.net.
francetv.fr.edgesuite.net is an alias for a253.w5.akamai.net.
a253.w5.akamai.net has address 23.3.13.170
a253.w5.akamai.net has address 23.3.13.176
```

The exact address your computer is given when looking up the hostname depends on your geographical location; by resolving the DNS aliases, the DNS server uses *your* IP address to guess what server might be closer to you in the network.

It may well be that the updates are rolled out to the CDN machines gradually, or you are given a different IP address to contact later on, after the first DNS lookup has expired. Either way, there is little you can do about this from Python; unless you know the origin server (which is usually **not** disclosed by a website to avoid overloading), you have to go with the normal flow of CDN updates.

Comment: Ok, thanks for theses precisions. I will add a `try/except`, and add a message in my program "try later!" :)